# adding a timeline to Jira

Tags: gratis, library

I'm looking to add a timeline to Jira, to allow sprint and resource planning.

I was thinking about [Portfolio](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/portfolio) but I'm not sure as the modules in Jira are plenty.

Any feedback on Portfolio? If there are others recommandation, I'm all ears.

PS : I have a budget of around 500 euros, not sure if Prospect is around that budget but if it can be gratis, I'm all ears as well.

Comment: Do you have a budget in mind? If so, please state it, else use the [tag:gratis]  tag.  It might help to read [ask]. The more details you can give us, the better that we can help you. Welcome aboard, I hope that you get an answer :-)